# $_SERVER['SELF']

Tags: php

I am trying to modify this :

```
enter echo "<a href=\"  " . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . "?c=$catId&p=$pd_id" . "<br>$pd_name</a><br>Price : $pd_price" . "</br>"; here
```

I want it to display in a different page, so i ended up doing this:

`echo "<a href=\"showcat.php?c=$catId&p=$pd_id\">$pd_name</a>";`

I created a page showcat.php to retrieve the data, but it tells me every time that the page doesn't exist.
I just don't wanna use $_SERVER['SELF'].
thank fellas

Comment: What is the content of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

Comment: with URLs, I would go against embedding the variable directly in and use <code>"?c=" . $catId . "&p=" . $pd_id</code>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']? It gives the URI which the page was accessed.

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Comment: Not a page, only a server.